# Pass child state to parent to open and close menu component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I have been trying for hours now and i can't get it to work, please help me out here.

I don't understand what is wrong with my code... An example below

```
// Parent component
export default (props) => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)

    const handleChildStatus = (childStatus) => {
        console.log(childStatus)
        setStatus(childStatus)
    }

    return (
        <header>
            <Menu
                childstatus={handleChildStatus}
                status={status}
                className={
                    status ? 'menu-wrapper show-menu' : 'menu-wrapper hide-menu'
                }
            />
            <div className="open-menu" onClick={() => setStatus(true)}></div>
        </header>
    )
}

// Menu component
export default (props) => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div
            childstatus={props.childstatus(status)}
            className={props.className}
        >
            <div onClick={() => setStatus(false)}>
                <img src={CloseMenu} alt="close-menu" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So with the code below I want to toggle the `Menu component` on and off.

In `parent` there is a menu button to open it, in the `Menu component` itself there is a button to close it. The `state` is not flowing correctly between the 2 components and i would like to get some help on how to achieve this logic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of maintaining status in child component you can handle it from parent's status variable like show below:

```
// Menu component
export default (props) => {
    return (
        <div
            className={props.className}
        >
            <div onClick={() => props.childstatus(false)}> // on click call parent's handleChildStatus function so in next render it will give hide class
                <img src={CloseMenu} alt="close-menu" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more detailed about it Abhay? Still not really could make it work ...

Comment: Can you check Menu Component has hide-menu class after clicking on img tag?

Comment: I'm expecting show-menu class will showing MenuComponent div and hide-menu is adding some css property like display none or visibility: hidden, is it right?

Comment: That is right, but with your code example i just get error: `childstatus' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: So if you could make a full working code example, that would really help me out :)

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: I think you need to edit parent comp as well

Comment: The only thing that happens with current code is `status returns false`, it never returns `true`

Comment: Ok figured it out, the following had to be deleted `childstatus={props.childstatus(status)}`